# Converting string array to integer array from SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite, type-conversion

Friends I have created an integer array qlist[] and it has some elements.
Now i have inserted this integer array to data base in form of String as

```
Arrays.toString(qlist)
```

Now when i get it back again from db in future, I want to convert that string into 
Integer array ..
Eg.

```
int[] qlist={13,4,12};
```

in database it looks like

```
[13,4,12]
```

as a string.

Comment: Follow this http://stackoverflow.com/a/6347763/1405983

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all save your String in a string variable.you need to remove [] brackets and then split your string by comma(,).

then you will have an string array containing only 1,2,3 values.you can easly convert them to integer by its position.
here i have given the code for it.hope it will help.

```
String arr = "[1,2]";
 String[] items = arr.replaceAll("\\[", "").replaceAll("\\]", "").split(",");

 int[] results = new int[items.length];

for (int i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    try {
       results[i] = Integer.parseInt(items[i]);
    } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {};
 }
```